# Uninstall Netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-15.10

I've been struggling all afternoon installing netbeans 8.1 on ubuntu 15.10.
But after many bugs, i decided to uninstall it. The problem is that I can't... I executed the uninstall.sh file but it shows me an error and after I click uninstall, all the files are still there.
[image]

[image]

I wanted the last version of netbeans so I downloaded the installer on the official site because on the repository it's not the latest version.

How can I uninstall my version cleanly ?

Comment: how did you install ? - using apt-get or the netbeans downloader ?

Comment: the netbeans downloader

Comment: did you use ```sudo``` to run the downloader ? are you using ```sudo``` to run the uninstall script ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

You may want to try uninstalling using

Go to your Netbeans(`/usr/local/netbeans.x.x`) path than execute below command

```
 sudo sh uninstall.sh
```

..

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1: Uninstall just netbeans**
sudo apt-get remove netbeans

**STEP 2: Uninstall netbeans and its dependencies**
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove netbeans

**STEP 3: Purging your config/data too**
sudo apt-get purge netbeans

Or similarly, like this netbeans

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove netbeans

Answer (score 0):

the best and perfect answer is to remove netbeans from ubuntu any version is

```
sudo snap remove netbeans
```